# How do I go about auto-mounting my NTFS hard drive at boot?

Tags: boot, mount, fstab, ntfs

There are questions similar to this one, but I am not an expert Unix user so I really don't wanna try and break /etc/fstab while doing this. Here's what `blkid` tells me about my hard drive:

`/dev/sda1: LABEL="X" UUID="9C4A70404A7018EA" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="7d4613d7-01"`

I always mount my drive at `/media/pi/X`, it is formatted in NTFS and I need both read and write permissions on it. The drive's `UUID` is `9C4A70404A7018EA` and my `userid`is `1000`. I know this post is very redundant, but I really cannot mess this up.

I've read [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/164926/how-to-make-partitions-mount-at-startup) from askubunto.com, so I know that a common setup is of this kind:

`UUID=<uuid> <pathtomount> <filesystem> defaults 0 0`

However, I do not understand some parts and would rather play it safe. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you installed ntfs-3g, because you will need that to write to the disk?

Comment: Yeah, since there's no native support I had to install it early on.

Comment: What is your OS? if it is Raspbian, why are you looking on an Ubuntu site? have you seen [this Raspberrypi.org document?](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/external-storage.md)?

Comment: I am running Raspbian, figured it wouldn't be so different. Thanks for the link. I already knew that I was just looking for confirmation on how the new line at /etc/fstab would have to be formatted. Thanks again.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Buster does not need ntfs-3g installed to write to it, it can be done with the stock image/install.

Comment: Speed is better with ntfs-3g.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know you are trying to replace an automount.

`fstab` is confusing, the documentation for `mount` is somewhat clearer.

If you are happy with the way automount works I suggest you let your system automount, then issue the `mount` command and copy the settings.

The following is a line from my `fstab`.
I use `noauto` and manually mount, but if you want to mount on boot you should use `nofail`

```
UUID=4AF49046F4903663       /mnt/SeagateNTFS     ntfs   rw,noauto,relatime,umask=22,uid=0,gid=0,nls=utf8    0   0
```

I would recommend against mounting in `/media` which is (ab)used by automount.

PS I rarely use NTFS, and you should probably use `ntfs-3g` if planning to write.

Comment: I have to say, I formatted my USB external hard drive to ext4 to take complete advantage of the RPI4's USB-3 and gigabit Ethernet capability. Using NTFS it was woefully slow as a shared drive using Samba, but with ext4 I can get transfer speeds of 900 to 1000 Mbit/sec.

Comment: Thank you that's actually really well explained. I like the way auto-mount works, and I am indeed planning on writing on the drive, so should I replace `ntfs-3g` with `ntfs` in the line? Using `nofail` instead of `noauto` exactly where `noauto` is? Also, is it okay to use the rest of your line exactly as it is? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This is the line in my /etc/fstab for a Toshiba Canvio 1 TB usb drive. Your UUID and mount points will be different.

<sub>UUID=A0027BBF027B994C /media/pi/Toshiba ntfs-3g defaults,auto,umask=000,users,rw,nofail 0 0</sub>